# How to space these images using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

Here's what I have now

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

I was able to space it out myself before, but my code was accidentally deleted and I can't figure out how I got it the first time.

HTML

```css
  /*images*/
    
    .img1 {
      display: inline-block;
      }
      
    .img2 {
      display: inline-block;
      }
      
    .img3 {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="topinfo">
                  <div id="images">
                    <div class="img1">
                         <h1 class="">- About -</h1>
                        <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/lljpxsf3gbe-nick-turner.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                        <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the about page.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img2">
                         <h1 class="">- Contact -</h1>
    
                        <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/portfolio-7.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                        <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the contact page.</p>
                 </div>
                    <div class="img3">
                         <h1 class="">- Page -</h1>
    
                        <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/photography-349870_19201.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                        <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the page.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I would collapse `.img1`, `.img2` and `.img3` into a single class/selector.

Comment: The image links in your post are already broken, would you repair them?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.img1, .img2, .img3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0 15px;
  }
 #images h1{
 text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="topinfo">
              <div id="images">
                <div class="img1">
                     <h1 class="">- About -</h1>
                    <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/lljpxsf3gbe-nick-turner.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                    <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the about page.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="img2">
                     <h1 class="">- Contact -</h1>

                    <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/portfolio-7.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                    <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the contact page.</p>
             </div>
                <div class="img3">
                     <h1 class="">- Page -</h1>

                    <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/photography-349870_19201.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                    <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the page.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I would collapse `.img1`, `.img2` and `.img3` into a single class/selecotr.

Comment: It just makes things either. You don't have to, but instead of restating .img1, img2 and img3 and giving each the same css, you can put commas after each class so that way the same css is applied to all 3. But with less code.

Comment: Using a single class/selector would make things much easier, understandable and maintainable. As it stands, there's no valid reason in having three separate classes (even if they're comma separated and not defined individually).

Answer (score 1):

You should rename your class names of `img1`, `img2`, and `img3` to just `img`. You need to take advantage of using CSS class.

With the following updated HTML code:

```
<div id="images">
    <div class="img">..</div>
    <div class="img">..</div>
    <div class="img">..</div>
</div>
```

And use CSS Flexbox feature to for such desired effects.

```
.images {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Another value you can assign to `justify-content` attribute is`space-between`. You can also learn more about Flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you for not re-using unnecessary classes and identifying a teachable moment.

Comment: Absolutely, though the updated CSS class is not in use in the provided solution. He should find it very useful in his specific requirements going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center` to `#images`

CSS:

```
#images {
  text-align: center;
}

.img1 {
  display: inline-block;
  }

.img2 {
  display: inline-block;
  }

.img3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some margin to the right and align text to center.

```css
      /*images*/
            
    #images{ 
       text-align: center; 
     }

    .img1 {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 25px;
     }
              
     .img2 {
         display: inline-block;
         margin-right: 25px;
     }
              
     .img3 {
          display: inline-block;
     }
```

```html
 <div class="topinfo">
                          <div id="images">
                            <div class="img1">
                                 <h1 class="">- About -</h1>
                                <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/lljpxsf3gbe-nick-turner.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                                <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the about page.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="img2">
                                 <h1 class="">- Contact -</h1>
            
                                <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/portfolio-7.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                                <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the contact page.</p>
                         </div>
                            <div class="img3">
                                 <h1 class="">- Page -</h1>
            
                                <img src="https://mycodingtest.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/photography-349870_19201.jpg?w=825" width="340" height="240" class="">
                                <p class="">This is just a short excerpt for the page.</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```